# Making all images the same size by overriding CSS code

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I have been struggling with creating a webshop recently.

I have over 1000 pictures imported into a webshop but all of them are different sizes. I am creating a web page using Elementor, which refuses to force the images to be the same size. I have tried using developer tools to see the CSS and can see the following:

```
<img width="360" height="360" src="https://gronlundsjf.se/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/82830-550-138-360x360.png" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" srcset="https://gronlundsjf.se/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/82830-550-138-360x360.png 360w, https://gronlundsjf.se/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/82830-550-138-300x300.png 300w, https://gronlundsjf.se/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/82830-550-138-150x150.png 150w, https://gronlundsjf.se/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/82830-550-138-400x400.png 400w, https://gronlundsjf.se/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/82830-550-138-100x100.png 100w" sizes="(max-width: 360px) 100vw, 360px" data-wp-pid="23261">

<img width="360" height="360" src="https://gronlundsjf.se/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/82830-550-138-360x360.png" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" srcset="https://gronlundsjf.se/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/82830-550-138-360x360.png 360w, https://gronlundsjf.se/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/82830-550-138-300x300.png 300w, https://gronlundsjf.se/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/82830-550-138-150x150.png 150w, https://gronlundsjf.se/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/82830-550-138-400x400.png 400w, https://gronlundsjf.se/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/82830-550-138-100x100.png 100w" sizes="(max-width: 360px) 100vw, 360px" data-wp-pid="23261">
```

As you can see, the images have specified width and height in the code. I want to add a CSS line to make sure that all of the images are the same size and override this code.

In the developer tools I have tried to untick the "height:auto" line and everything seems to work fine.
I am just not sure how to target all the pictures or how to adress the correct class.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Set a class for your products image, i'm calling it **'myproducts'.**

```
.myproducts{
     width: 360px;
     height: 360px;
    }
```

in html, set it like this ...

It should work for you.

Comment: This kind of worked... I managed to get the product images to be the same size this way but this ´forces all images on the website to be the same size... For example, the admin icon in wordpress etc.